# Things dont show after I click my button swing Java

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, swing

(Watch out SoMania got me!)So my title isnt very good because its hard to explain my problem. So my problem is afer I click my button on my app and i remove button and clear my screen it needs to show some text area for some calculation. But when i click button and everything removes i need to maximize or resize my window for TextArea and label to appear. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
package igrica;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Cijena{
    JButton button;
    JFrame frame;
   JTextField field;
    JPanel panel;
   JLabel label;
   JLabel label2;
   JTextField field2;
   JButton button2;
   JLabel rjesenje2;

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Cijena gui = new Cijena();
    gui.go();
} 

public void go() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}
    panel = new JPanel();
    rjesenje2 = new JLabel();
    label = new JLabel("Upisite cijenu bez popusta: ");
    label2 = new JLabel("Upisite cijenu s popustom: ");
    field2 = new JTextField(20);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    button2 = new JButton("Izracunaj");
    //panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    frame = new JFrame("Matematicki programi za apartmane");
    button = new JButton("Razlika u cijeni");
    button.addActionListener(new CijenaListener());
    button2.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    field = new JTextField(20);
    field.addActionListener(new TextListener());

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
}

class CijenaListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        frame.repaint();
        frame.getContentPane().remove(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(field);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        //frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        //frame.getContentPane().add(label2);
        //frame.getContentPane().add(field2);
        //TestPane pane = new TestPane();
        //pane.TestPane();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(field2);
        panel.add(button2);
    }
}
class TextListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String text = field.getText();
        field.setText("");
    }
}
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        String input1 = field.getText();
        String input2 = field2.getText();
        field.setText("");
        field2.setText("");
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(input1);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);

        double rjesenje = (double)number2 / number1;
        rjesenje *= 100;
        int r = 100 - (int)rjesenje;
        //System.out.println(number1 + " " + number2);
        String solution = Integer.toString(r);
        rjesenje2.setText(solution + "%");
        panel.add(rjesenje2);
    }
}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: When dynamically updating the ui, you will need to use revalidate followed by repaint AFTER you've updated the ui. You should also be calling super.paintComponent before you do any custom painting

Comment: Consider using a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: Could yout please explain it to me? Im not that good with java Im still learning it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `frame.revalidate();` at the end of your `actionPerformed`Method.